# Read PWM Signal from Pixhawk to Arduino

Tags: arduino, pwm

I tried to read a PWM signal from Pixhawk by connecting it to Arduino.
The Pixhawk is connected to FrSky X8R. But my PWM always reads to zero.

Here's my arduino code

```
#define RCPin 4
int RCValue;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RCPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  RCValue = pulseIn(RCPin, HIGH,25000);
  Serial.println(RCValue);
}
```

The picture attached is also my wiring.

[image]

Comment: Can't see too much wrong with the code. Are you definitely getting a pwm signal from the pixhawk? Do you have a servo you could connect it to? Have you tried reading from one of the frsky pwm channels to test the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all pin 4 isn't a PWM pin. As i can see you're using Arduino UNO. In UNO PWM pins are: `3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11`
And their Frequencies: `490 Hz` except pin 5 and pin 6, their frequencies is: `980 Hz`.

So, change your pin as 5 and it will work then.